# How to do ParseQuery for each item in a list of ParseObjects

Tags: android, kotlin, parse-platform

I want to do ParseAPI call in Kotlin where input is `List<ParseObject>` and output is update `MutableList<CustomObject>` where `CustomObject` is data class containing `ParseObject` and `Int`. I can do something like this:

```
var newItems = mutableListOf<CustomObject>()
items.forEach{
//do query on relation column of item
//inside query.findInBackground -> (if error == null) add item to newItems
}
```

But I need to call callback function when new list is finished. I need something like await function for this call. Because i have to wait till callbacks for each item have ended and then return results to Activity.

That means function for query is defined like this:

```
fun getCurrentItems(c: Context, items: List<ParseObject>, callback:(MutableList<CustomObject>) -> Unit)
```

If all items were checked I just want to call:

```
callback(newItems)
```

Comment: Could you chain a `.also{ callback() }` onto the end of your foreach statement?

Comment: And will it work? Because inside foreach is query.findInBackground which is async call with onDone function

Comment: No probably not, sorry missed that detail. How many results do you expect back? If it's a small amount you could use an intent to notify the activity of changes. You'd use a data store pattern instead of a callback.

Comment: Can be 4 but also 300 items

Comment: Have you tried to use the ```query.find()``` method instead of the ```query.findInBackground()```? This method is synchronous and will probably solve your problem.